# Django, trouble with STATIC_URL file paths

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two templates index.html and search_results.html in the same directory.

Both have the following code snippet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
```

The css file loads on the index template:

```
"GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

However, does not for the search_results template:

```
"GET /search/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2133
```

Since it includes the /search.

I'm wondering how to omit the /search/ portion in trying to load the css file in my second template, since that template all have urls starting with /search/.

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'home.views.index'),
    url(r'^search/$', 'home.views.film_chart_view')

)
```

Comment: Can you show the STATIC_URL settings variable as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, you are missing the slash `/` at the beginning of the static URL.

The dirty fix:
Change the line in your template to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
```

The clean fix:
Add a slash at the beginning of the `STATIC_URL` variable in your settings file. It must probably look like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```